# Why UIActivityIndicatorView is not showing on UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

Code:

```
CGPoint centerPoint = [_inner_web_view center];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, 100, 100);
_activity_indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                       initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[_activity_indicator setFrame:frame];
[_inner_web_view addSubview:_activity_indicator];
```

What I need is to display ActivityIndicator on UIWebView.
Even after using [_activity_indicator startAnimating] nothing happens. :(

Can someone help me find out WHY this happens?

Comment: Either the webview's nil, or it's acting up.  Regardless, take a log of it's subviews to check if your view is even in there.

Comment: Solved my problem changing style to Gray, I have tested indicator on white web view :(

Comment: Ah!  Well, contrasting colors usually help.  You are allowed to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Activity Indicator View's` Style is White `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite` and `UIWebView` also has white background when loading. Try Gray Style `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray`.